# Interoperation Python JavaScript RSA Encryption

Tags: javascript, python, encryption, rsa, transferable

Python with PyCrypto on Server, Tom Wu's JavaScript library on Client. http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~tjw/jsbn/
I can encrypt and decrypt in Python on Server, and do the same in JavaScript on client. But I cannot encrypt on the client and decrypt the same on the server. 
The subject has been discussed earlier, but no solution has been delivered.

in Python:

```
  key = RSA.generate(2048, e=65537)
  pri_key = key.exportKey()
  n = key.n

  session['S_publicKey']  = n
  session['S_privateKey'] = pri_key

  publicKey_IntN = session.get('S_publicKey')
  publicKey_HexN = hex(publicKey_IntN)[2:].rstrip("L")  

  render_template('Shop.html', t1=publicKey_HexN )
```

in Shop.html (JavaScript):

```
function submitToPython() {
  var d1 = document.getElementById('input1').value;
  var d2 = document.getElementById('input2').value;

  var strJSON = JSON.stringify({data1:d1,data2:d2});   
  var publicKey_HexStrN = sessionStorage.getItem("SpublicKey");

  jsonRsa = do_encrypt(strJSON, publicKey_HexStrN);

  document.getElementById("messageJSON").value = jsonRsa;
  document.getElementById('input1').value = "";
  document.getElementById('input2').value = "";
  document.getElementById("form1").action = "/Order";
  document.getElementById("form1").method = "POST";
  document.getElementById("form1").submit();
}

function do_encrypt(strIn, nKey) {
  var rsa = new RSAKey();
  rsa.setPublic( nKey, "10001" );   # also tested "0x10001"
  var strOut = rsa.encrypt(strIn);
  return strOut;
}
```

in Python:

```
  jsonrsa    = request.form['messageJSON']     
  jsonrsa    = codecs.decode( jsonrsa, 'hex' ) 
  #jsonrsa    = jsonrsa.encode('utf-8')  # in Python 3, must pass bytes 

  privateKey = session.get('S_privateKey')
  jsonStr = decrypt_string(jsonrsa,privateKey)  # ERROR invalid decryption

def decrypt_string(encrypted,private_key):    
    rsakey = RSA.importKey(private_key)
    rsakey = PKCS1_OAEP.new(rsakey)    

    chunk_size = 256
    offset     = 0    
    decrypted  = ""   

    while offset < len(encrypted):
        decrypted += rsakey.decrypt(encrypted[offset:offset+chunk_size])
        offset += chunk_size    

    return decrypted
```

Comment: Calling `codecs.decode` and then ignoring the result doesn’t do anything. So, in Python, you’re not treating the input as hex, your just convert each hex digit to its ASCII byte value.

Comment: changed to, jsonrsa = codecs.decode( jsonrsa, 'hex' ),  but still the same error.

Comment: Since you haven’t told us what error that is, that isn’t very helpful. But even if it’s the same error type, I doubt it’s the same actual problem.

Comment: Yes it's the same error, invalid decryption.